# FQL: get all posts on My wall

Tags: facebook-fql

Folks - can someone share some FQL (other other graph query) to show my how I can query my own wall to list out all the posts.

I've tried things like

```
SELECT post_id, message 
FROM stream where source_id = me()
and created_time > 946684800 AND created_time < now()
```

but (obviously) it only shows my my own posts. however, if I remove the `source_id=me()` then it errors out and tells me I need to include an indexable column.

**Edit** - this seems to work...

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() ) order by updated_time desc
```

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: `source_id` should give you posts from others as well, as it indicates the owner of the wall, not who posted – are you sure there are posts by others in that time interval? Anyway, you could also try with a `filter_key`, that is indexable as well.

Comment: hmm - I dont think that's it - I really do only see my posts - I wonder if it's something to do with this... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/